# How to access the form's 'name' variable from PHP

Tags: php, forms

I'm trying to create a BMI calculator. This should allow people to use either metric or imperial measurements.

I realise that I could use hidden tags to solve my problem, but this has bugged me before so I thought I'd ask: I can use `$_POST['variableName']` to find the submitted variableName field-value; but...I don't know, or see, how to verify which form was *used* to submit the variables.

My code's below (though I'm not sure it's strictly relevant to the question):

```
<?php
    $bmiSubmitted     = $_POST['bmiSubmitted'];

    if (isset($bmiSubmitted)) {
        $height        = $_POST['height'];
        $weight        = $_POST['weight'];
        $bmi        = floor($weight/($height*$height));

        ?>
            <ul id="bmi">
            <li>Weight (in kilograms) is: <span><?php echo "$weight"; ?></span></li>

            <li>Height (in metres) is: <span><?php echo "$height"; ?></span></li>

            <li>Body mass index (BMI) is: <span><?php echo "$bmi"; ?></span></li>

            </ul>
        <?php
    }

    else {
    ?>

    <div id="formSelector">

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#metric">Metric</a></li>
        <li><a href="#imperial">Imperial</a></li>
    </ul>

        <form name="met" id="metric" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="form/multipart">

            <fieldset>
                <label for="weight">Weight (<abbr title="Kilograms">kg</abbr>):</label>
                    <input type="text" name="weight" id="weight" />

                <label for="height">Height (<abbr title="metres">m</abbr>):</label>
                    <input type="text" name="height" id="height" />

                <input type="hidden" name="bmiSubmitted" id="bmiSubmitted" value="1" />
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <input type="reset" id="reset" value="Clear" />

                <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
            </fieldset>
        </form>

        <form name="imp" id="imperial" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="form/multipart">

            <fieldset>

            <label for="weight">Weight (<abbr title="Pounds">lbs</abbr>):</label>
                <input type="text" name="weight" id="weight" />

            <label for="height">Height (Inches):</label>
                <input type="text" name="height" id="height" /
            <input type="hidden" name="bmiSubmitted" id="bmiSubmitted" value="1" />
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <input type="reset" id="reset" value="Clear" />
                <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
            </fieldset>
        </form>

    <?php
    }
?>
```

I verified that it worked (though without validation at the moment -I didn't want to crowd my question too much) with metric; I've added the form but not the processing for the imperial yet.

Comment: As some have noted below, the form's name shouldn't really be important. If you need to distinguish data from one form or another it's probably better for each form to have a different action.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

To identify the submitted form, you can use:

- A hidden input field.
- The name or value of the submit button.

The name of the form is not sent to the server as part of the [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) data.

You can use code as follows:

```html
<form name="myform" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="frmname" value=""/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 18):

You can do it like this:

```html
<input type="text" name="myform[login]">
<input type="password" name="myform[password]">
```

Check the posted values

```
if (isset($_POST['myform'])) {
    $values = $_POST['myform'];

    // $login = $values['login'];
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I really like that way of going about it!  My only question is, how would that work with input groups like checkboxes or radios?  Is `name="myform[chkgrp][]"` valid?

Answer (score 13):

The form name is not submitted. You should just add a hidden field to each form and call it a day.

Comment: Really? That seems like a half-hearted implementation of forms... o.O Still, I feel better for being unable to see how it works.

Comment: @ricebowl, A form's name is only useful for DOM manipulations and such.

Comment: @ricebowl: understand, too, that this is how HTTP works. It has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: @Strager, I hadn't realised that 'til now. I thought it would have more use, for some reason.

@Narcissus, I was intending my criticism, unjust as it may be, to be read as against browsers/http, rather than php.

Answer (score 9):

In the form submitting button (id method of form is `post`):

```
<input type="submit" value="save" name="commentData">
```

In the PHP file:

```
if (isset($_POST['commentData'])){
    // Code
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For some reason, the name of the submit button is not passed to the superglobal [$_POST](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) when submitted with Ajax/jQuery.

Comment: That may be true, but how does that answer the question? Can you elaborate? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21206518/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 3):

Use a unique value on the submit button for each form like so

#### File *index.html*

```html
<form method="post" action="bat/email.php">
    <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First name" required>
    <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Last name" required>
    <button name="submit" type="submit" value="contact">Send Message</button>
</form>

<form method="post" action="bat/email.php">
    <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First name" required>
    <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Last name" required>
    <button name="submit" type="submit" value="support">Send Message</button>
</form>
```

#### File *email.php*

```php
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        switch ($_POST["submit"]) {
            case "contact":
                break;
            case "support":
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

As [petervandijck.com](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22192/petervandijck-com) pointed out, this code may be susceptible to XSS attacks if you have it behind some kind of log-in system or have it embedded in other code.

To prevent an XSS attack, where you have written:

```
<?php echo "$weight"; ?>
```

You should write instead:

```
<?php echo htmlentities($weight); ?>
```

Which could even be better written as:

```
<?=htmlentities($weight); ?>
```

Comment: <? ?> is not supported everywhere. I noticed some shared hosting, even when up-to-date has the option switch off in the php configuration file, even when php version is up-to-date

Comment: This should be a comment to the question, not an answer.

Comment: The link is broken. Are you referring to [PeterV's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846020/how-to-access-the-forms-name-variable-from-php/847819#847819)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use GET in the form's action parameter, which I use whenever I make a login/register combined page.

For example: `action="loginregister.php?whichform=loginform"`

Comment: Re *"GET"*: Isn't it customary to use *"get"* (lowercase) (not a rhetorical question)?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem which brought me to this question. I reviewed all the preceding answers, but ultimately I ending up figuring out my own solution:

```html
<form name="ctc_form" id="ctc_form" action='' method='get'>

    <input type="hidden" name="form_nm" id="form_nm">

    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('form_nm').value=this.closest('form').name;">Submit</button>

</form>
```

It seamlessly and efficiently accomplishes the following:

- Passes the form **name** attribute via a **hidden input** field, without using the fallible **value** attribute of the **submit** button.
- Works with both [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) and [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) methods.
- Requires no additional, independent JavaScript.

Comment: Hi James thanks for your answer it was helpful to me. Could you please expand on why the submit button's value is fallable, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Only the names of the form fields are submitted, but the name of the form itself is not. But you can set a hidden field with the name in it.

Answer (score 0):

You could just give a name to the submit button and do what needs to be done based on that. I have several forms on a page and do just that. Pass the button name and then if button name = button name do something.