# how to get a input field's name via PHP GET

Tags: php, forms, get, attributes

There is an example what I want to do: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_datetime

In this example, if you change the input's name, on the right side of screen (after submitting code), you'll see the changed name. And also, as you can see there is **no hidden input field** to get the name of input automatically. Because I searched for some answers and they say "use an hidden input field" like in this: [How to access the form's 'name' variable from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846020/how-to-access-the-forms-name-variable-from-php) But I need it exactly in the w3schools.

Of course this is an .asp example but I hope there is a way for this via PHP also?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where exactly do you see form's name on the right side?

Comment: It is the input name you see.

Comment: @Indianer ah ok sorry. I edited. But I still have my question. Thanks.

Comment: There is no way to do it as stated in the other question's answer.

Comment: @Indianer then how about the example of w3? they did it how? Thanks.

Comment: ?? You cannot get the form name. w3 is getting the INPUT NAME! `bdaytime`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all input field name using post method.

you can use `$GET` or `$REQUEST` instead of `$POST`.

`$REQUEST` use with both GET and POST.
 In php `$POST` is a one type of associative array.

```
<?php
$temp= array();
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit'])) {
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
        //$key is the name you wanted, and $val is the value of that input
        $temp[] = $key;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I tried that now and then tried `print_r ($temp);` but the result is nothing.

Comment: btw, i added `if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {
echo "hello";` to try, and it doesn't print "hello" to screen.

Comment: ok I used GET instead of POST, and it works perfect. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    foreach($_POST as $key => $val) {
        print $key . " = " . $val;
     }
 ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$_GET['bdaytime'];
```

using the above code.

Comment: I don't think this will answer the question the user has asked. Also please elaborate.