# Contact form specific to a certain page/post

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form

Im using wordpress to display courses where the visitor can book a place if interested using a contact form (contactform7).

What Im doing today is letting the costumer write the name of the course so that I know which course to sign him/her up to. Ive had several complaints about this and some misses where I accidentally signed a customer on to the wrong course.

What I need to know is if there is a way in which I can make a contact form that is specific to the post/course that the customer wants to sign up on.

A friend told me to create a contact form for every post/course (contact form A has the same name as course A)

This wont work for me as I have new content often and it would mean that Ide have to spend my days creating contact forms.

Thank you!

Comment: Create dynamic drop down lists, one which has the courses and based on the course they select generate the schedules in another drop down.  Another option is to combine a course drop down with a calendar. If these course id's are stored in the database you would use a db query and a loop to give each course it's own id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in html it is called **id** or if you want **name** of the form, div, etc.
and then you just assign your form to that id then you extract them from $_POST and you're done

I think there you can find some answers:

http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/9986-get-form-name-id

[How to access the form's 'name' variable from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846020/how-to-access-the-forms-name-variable-from-php)